what dotfile can do in the tails
when the user read thier   section of the Persistent Storage  he will see  they explain about Dotfiles as a way to save  configurtion of the apps can it save the log in in websites or it just save the prefecne of useing the app    so    how can I use dotfile feature
if the dotefile feature can not used to save log in so please suggest for me a distro that is live os (which only run from flash and dont fromat my laptop ) and at the same time save my logs

What you want to do defeats the purpose of Tails.
Tails, "The Amnesic Incognito Live System", is a privacy-hardened OS designed not to write on the hard drive / SSD with the purpose not to leave any digital footprint on the machine. Saving your logins on websites goes to the opposite direction.
In short, don't use Tails if you want (or need) your data to be saved on the system. You can use Tor on any other OS.

so their isnt any way to remain my logs in ? just I need telegram to remain loges in becuse i dont use mobile just my linux desktop ,,, and i like to have two os one for home and for the university so is there any way to have two os in my laptop with out using vertiualtion

Sure, you can install two OSes on your laptop.  Google for "dual boot".

aha nice I ll ... but why  google !!! I think every body here appreciate free open source and admire Mr.stallman
